# Any new texts directly on second law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, equilibrium, non-equilibrium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommendations for Statistical Mechanics book](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30550/recommendations-for-statistical-mechanics-book)

Is anyone aware of any recent text that summarises the research and arguments on second law of thermodynamics and also on the foundations of statistical mechanics and thermodynamics (equilibrium and non equilibrium) and names of any present prominent professors working in the same fields so that I can look up relevant material. The only big name I found last was Ilya Prigogine, any references on any good work continuing Prigogine?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30550/2451

Comment: Hi excitedaboutphysics - we only allow a specific, limited set of book recommendations, and statistical mechanics/thermodynamics is already covered.

Comment: have a look at books by Georgy Lebon, David Jou, José Casas Vázquez. There are several, several editions, get the one you can. Actually I don't see how is the question duplicates the linked one.

Comment: thanks Yrogirg for the book reference, i was searching for something like that.