# Book recommendation for statistical physics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education, topological-order, critical-phenomena

Before I start a PhD in Quantum Information I would like to study a bit of statistical physics. In particular I am interested in superfluids, critical phenomena, topological phases of matter and all that. Note that I am a theoretical physicist, so I am interested in the role of QFT (statistical field theory). Is there any book that covers all of this? Also I would like something not too thorough. I just want the big picture for now. Even a nice review would do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommendations for statistical mechanics book](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30550/recommendations-for-statistical-mechanics-book)

Comment: No it doens't. It helps, but I'm looking for something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Xiao-Gang Wen's 'Quantum Field Theory of Many-Body Systems' is probably a good place to start. It will give you some 'big picture' information, but asking for something 'not too thorough' is likely to leave you with little. Xiao-Gang's book is excellent, but it will require that you step up to it. The advantage to that is that you'll need to step up to it anyway and it's excellent for helping do that.