# Suggest good books on Statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I' m looking at books that take the historical aproach (like  "A Radical Approach to Real Analysis" by
David M. Bressoud does for calculus) but with all of the formalism.
i.e most of the math should be there but also the history (the failures and the experiments) and the philosophy (justifications)  of the great thinkers/founders of the subject.
Of course such a book would have to be enormous if it contained everything! so a curated connected path through major achivements with plenty of references for what's left out is also required.
In short: something not for the layman but for someone that already has some exposure to the subject and needs some encompassing view of its devellopment .
The level of the math could be at least of graduate engineer level.

Comment: Try Resnick & Eisberg’s Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecules, Solids, Nuclei, and Particles, and then move on to Zetilli.I think that would be enough

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30550/2451 and links therein.