# Books recommendations!

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm currently a Physics major undergrad. I was wondering if you could recommend Statistical Mechanics books. At my university, we work with Concepts in Thermal Physics by Blundell, but I always prefer to have several books to consult before getting to a course.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30550/2451 and links therein.