# Help in Statistical Mechanics (Resource Recommendation)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I have statistical mechanics in my semester this year. It is a graduate level course. I am having trouble understanding the concepts. I have used Reif and Pathria for the same. Can you please suggest a book that builds from the ground up the concepts of statistical mechanics in detail?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [overarching books question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/168783), which includes links to many other questions concerning reference requests

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Recommendations for statistical mechanics book](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30550/168783)