# Good undergraduate statistical mechanics textbook

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm looking for a statistical mechanics textbook which covers upper-level undergraduate material, suitable for a course geared towards advanced undergraduates who have encountered thermodynamics before but not statistical mechanics proper.

(I have used Huang as a reference, and I like David Tong's book which is free online, but I think both textbooks assume some intuition and mathematical knowledge which upper-level undergraduates might not yet have. Looking for something which doesn't cost hundreds of dollars.)

Comment: I used Kittel and Kroemer

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30550/2451 and links therein.